# how to flip a bit at a specific position in an integer in any language

Tags: java, python, c

I have an integer `n`, and I want to flip its `k`th bit (from the lowest) in its binary representation. How can I do it?

For example, if I have `n=0b01101` and `k=2`, then the result is `0b01001=9`

Any language is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 37):

To flip one or more bits, use [binary XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Bitwise_operation). In your case, the appropriate XOR mask is `1` [shifted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting) `k` bits to the left.

In Python:

```
In [58]: 0b01101 ^ (1 << 2)
Out[58]: 9
```

The expression:

```
n ^ (1 << k)
```

is valid in C, Java, Python and a few other languages (provided the variables are appropriately defined).

Answer (score 9):

Left-shift the number 1 the number of digits you need, and then XOR the number.

JavaScript:

```
var num = 6, k = 2;
num = num ^ (1 << k);
```

What is happening:

```
num = 0b01101 XOR (0b00001 << 2)
num = 0b01101 XOR 0b00100
num = 0b01001
```

Answer (score 3):

In c you just do this to toggle it:

```
n ^= 1 << k;
```

but there are other ways of doing it like:

```
n |= ( 1 << k);
```

This shifts bit k to 1

Now if you want to flip the bit you can do an if statement with a unary and to see how you need to flip it

```
number = pow(2,k)    
if((number & n) != number)
    //this means that it's a 0 at position k
    n |= ( 1 << k);
else
    //this means that it's a 1 at position k
    n &= ( 0 << k);
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of `pow(2,k)`, you can use `(n >> k) & 1` to find the value at position **k** when **n** is an integer. Resulting in a RSHIFT instead of a function call, same can be said for the power operator`**`, though performance wise this is of little concern.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you'd do it in C:

```
n ^ (1 << k)
```

Answer (score 0):

(for googlers) here is how you can do it in VB6 without shifting

```
'flips a bit to the opposite of its current value
'1 based, left to right
Function FlipBit(ByVal FlipByte As Byte, ByVal bPosition As Byte) As Byte
    FlipBit = FlipByte Xor (2 ^ (8 - bPosition))
End Function

'example
 MyByte = 255
'mybyte is now "11111111"
 MyByte = FlipBit(MyByte,2)
'mybyte is now "10111111"
```